# Read next few lines in a multi-line file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a multi-line file I am parsing through to find a specific number, call it `67`.  After finding this number I would like to read the following three or four lines and append a list based on what follows.

For example:

Lines in file:

```
100
200
300
67
400
500
601
700
```

I know how to find 67 in the file but how could I read the next few lines in order to find either a 600 or 601?  Moreover, the file is not this simple.  It has lines before and after this "block."  I do not want to just find one 67 and read the three or four lines that follow, I would like to repeat this multiple times in one file.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To read the three or four lines that follow, you use readline() three or four times on the infile.

To repeat this multiple times in one file, you wrap everything in a while-loop, that you break out of when the file is empty.

There are several ways to implement the details in this, but you don't give any indication to what your actual problem is, so...

Comment: My problem is that the 67 appears randomly in the file.  So readline() wouldn't work for me because I would need to know what lines the 67 falls on then specificy the following four lines.  Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @user1082411: You are correct in that you need to find the 67, and then read the following four lines. You are wrong in that this means you can't use readline(), and I do not follow your thinking there. You can use readline().

Comment: @user1082411: At "So readline() wouldn't work for me". Yes it would. If you want to read the four lines following the "67", you read until you find the 67, and then you do four "readlines()". It really is that simple.